# Using apply() with a custom function and a second data frame

Tags: r, apply

I'm trying to generate predicted values from a large number of model simulations and I'm having a hard time doing it simply. I suspect I need something from the apply() family, but I can't figure out the syntax.  Maybe my knowledge of apply() is weak. Or maybe my function is wrong.  Any suggestions?

Suppose I've got following coefficients resulting from six model simulations...

```
coef <- data.frame(intercept=c(2,3,5,7,2,1),
                   b1 = c(.2,.5,.6,.7,.9,.4),
                   b2 = c(10,11,12,11,9,10))
```

I want to compute (predicted values or) the linear combination of each row above and each row of the following data frame...

```
df <- data.frame(age = c(50,20,19, 42),
                 height = c(60,72,79, 66))
```

...Using the following model equation:

```
coef$intercept + coef$b1*df$age + coef$b2*df$height
```

Done right, I should get the following 24 data values:

```
612.0   726.0   795.8   670.4
688.0   805.0   881.5   750
755.0   881.0   964.4   822.2
702.0   813.0   889.3   762.4
587.0   668.0   730.1   633.8
621.0   729.0   798.6   677.8
```

To get the above, I've tried the following function and use of apply()...

```
equation <-  function(...) coef$intercept + coef$b1*df$age + coef$b2*df$height
result <- apply(df, 1, equation)
```

...but I don't get the correct answer. The "result" data frame just repeats the correct diagonals. I also get the message:

```
> Warning messages: 1: In coef$b1 * df$age :   longer object length is
> not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Yes I can get the correct answer through simple matrix multiplication:

```
df$ones <- 1
df <- df[,c(3, 1, 2)]
result <- as.matrix(coef) %*% t(as.matrix(df))
```

But it seems to me one ought to be able to do this more generally using apply() and a custom function. Use of apply() is more compact and puts me less at risk of having my matrix columns in the wrong order.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

If you *really* want to use apply, you can do this:

```
result<- t(apply(coef, 1, function(x) x[1] + x[2]*df$age + x[3]*df$height))
> result
     [,1] [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
[1,]  612  726 795.8 670.4
[2,]  688  805 881.5 750.0
[3,]  755  881 964.4 822.2
[4,]  702  813 889.3 762.4
[5,]  587  668 730.1 633.8
[6,]  621  729 798.6 677.8
```

But it's really preferable (and faster) to do the matrix multiplication.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation that I should stick to matrix multiplication.  One thing about the answer above is that I'm nervous about referring to columns of "coef" by a numeric index.  I want to fool-proof the the function against my columns being in the wrong order.  But your answer inspires me to write:

`result<- t(apply(coef, 1, function(x) x["intercept"] + x["b1"]*df$age + x["b2"]*df$height))`

Answer (score 3):

We can do this with `%*%`

```
coef[,1] + as.matrix(coef[-1]) %*% t(df)
#     [,1] [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
#[1,]  612  726 795.8 670.4
#[2,]  688  805 881.5 750.0
#[3,]  755  881 964.4 822.2
#[4,]  702  813 889.3 762.4
#[5,]  587  668 730.1 633.8
#[6,]  621  729 798.6 677.8
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I'd do:

```
sapply(seq_along(1:nrow(coef)), function(x){

  sapply(seq_along(1:nrow(df)), function(y) {
    coef$intercept[[x]] + coef$b1[[x]]*df$age[[y]] + coef$b2[[x]]*df$height[[y]]
  })

})
```

Result:

```
     [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]
[1,] 612.0 688.0 755.0 702.0 587.0 621.0
[2,] 726.0 805.0 881.0 813.0 668.0 729.0
[3,] 795.8 881.5 964.4 889.3 730.1 798.6
[4,] 670.4 750.0 822.2 762.4 633.8 677.8
```

Use two sapplys. One for each object (`df` and `coef`).